# Unknown number of Parameters in GET request: Play Framework 2.3.x+ Twilio

Tags: rest, playframework, get, twilio, playframework-2.3

I am trying to point my twilio voice URl to my server.
So my routes files has this line:

```
GET     /v1/twilio/                 controllers.Application.call()
```

When I get the request from Twili, I get it as below:

```
/v1/twilio/?AccountSid=someRandomSID&
ToZip=0000&
FromState=A&
Called=%2B109213098234&
FromCountry=US&
CallerCountry=US&
CalledZip=9000&
Direction=inbound&
FromCity=xyz&
CalledCountry=US&
CallerState=A&
CallSid=randomSID&
CalledState=A&
From=%2B123455667&
CallerZip=90909&
FromZip=9890&
CallStatus=ringing&
ToCity=BLA&
ToState=AA&
To=%2B765213765&
ToCountry=PQR&
CallerCity=PT&
ApiVersion=2010-04-01&
Caller=%23123213&
CalledCity=BB]
```

SO you see, there are a lot of parameters. 
My problem is that I am Not aware of all the parameters.
So when I just put above line in my routes file, I get an Error: 404 Not found.

How should modify the routes file so that I get the GET request?
If I ask twilio to send me POST request, then I don't have to worry about it as then I can simply get the parameter I need by Querying thee RequestData.

But there has to be some way I can get GET REQUEST to succed and reach my application controller. 
Please help me here.

sorry if this is a silly question. But I am really struggling to get some info. 
PS: I am using 2.3X version of play framework

Also, I dont have the control over parameters sent by Twilio.
I will simply get a GET/POst request, as per this : https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/twilio_request#synchronous

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing unusual with this route, it works with sample URL like a charm (checked) maybe Twilio untrails return path by default? try to add *spare* route for handling this case as well:

```
GET     /v1/twilio        controllers.Application.call()
GET     /v1/twilio/       controllers.Application.call()
```

Comment: Thanks @biesior.  

I get the request from Twilio as  "GET /v1/twilio?delay=0&AccountSid=blablablabala......"  



When I make my routes as below, it worked:  

`GET     /v1/twilio                  controllers.Application.call()`

Comment: So de facto you need only first route, if this solves your problem, mark answer as correct

Comment: Thanks a lot. Of course, I will mark your answer as correct. Thanks again.